# Name of this Definition in Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

I would like to know if there is a name for the following definition :

> Let $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ and define $f : E \to \mathbb{R}$. Assume $E$ is not bounded bounded above, we say that $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=L\in\mathbb{R}$ if and only if for every $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $M\in\mathbb{R}$ such that forall $x>M$ we have $|f(x)-L|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: This is none other than the definition of the limit of function $f$ at the accumulation point $\infty$ that the domain of definition $E$ by hypothesis has in the ambient space $\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ (with the standard order topology). It is *not* a matter of continuity, but of limits.

Comment: Alright I understand your point thank you very much!

Comment: You are welcome!